# Prépositions: des vs de

Tags: prépositions, pluriel

Why in the sentence "Ce jardin est rempli de rosiers, de dalhias et de lauriers" do we use "de" instead of "des"?

I would figure that the garden is full of roses (plural)? Or is it dependent on the sentence's subject?

Comment: "des" is not a preposition. It is either a contraction of the prepostion "de" and the definite plural article "les", or it is an indefinite plural article (this is a specialized function of the word that etymologically derives from the contraction). "rempli **des** rosiers" would mean "full **of the** rose bushes". That is an odd thing to say; "full **of** rose bushes" is more common, and in French as in English, the indefinite plural is simply indicated in this context by using no article.